# Transforming between different Coordinate Systems

Tags: wpf, arcgis, esri-arc-engine

In my application, I require to locally transform from and to different Coordinate Projection Systems when building some GraphicsLayers.

I've seen that there is an ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Projection namespace, and the IProjection interface is defined, but only WebMercator implements it.

How can I perform these transformations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the JavaScript API there you would use the project method of the GeometryService (esri/tasks/GeometryService) to project a geometry from one spatial reference to another.  I haven't used the WPF based API but I have found the APIs to be generally quite similar.  So, have a look for a tasks namespace and see if there is something similar to the Geometry server - or look for anything that has a 'project' method.

Update: I just had a quick look on the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF API and there does seem to be the same functionality in ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GeometryService.Project.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.GeometryService~Project.html